# LifecycleOwner: difference between Fragment (self) and Fragment#viewLifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, androidx, android-architecture-components

Using `Android X` and the `Android Architecture Components`, namely the following...

- Navigation
- Lifecycle
- ViewModel

... has made Android development much easier for better and more stable apps.

When using a `ViewModel` exposing `LiveData`s for a `Fragment`, there are currently two **LifecycleOwners** that can be used to **oberve**:

1. the `Fragment` itself or
2. the `Fragment`'s property `mViewLifecycleOwner`.

Up until now, I have always and exclusively use the `Fragment` itself for any and all `LiveData` exposed by `ViewModel`s.

As I like to *live on the edge* by frequently upgrading to the latest alphas & betas, I have recently upgraded to:

- navigation ktx version `2.2.0-rc01` ;
- activity ktx version `1.1.0-rc01` ;
- fragment ktx version `1.2.0-rc01` ;
- lifecycle ktx version `2.2.0-rc01` ;

*OK luckily, at this date (1st nov 2019), there were all available as release candidates*.

This had the consequence to warn me in old java code:

[image]

How come there is actually two **LifecycleOwners** ?

Should I also follow this warning when setting the lifecycle owner of the Fragment's databound layout (using the `Databinding` library) ?

Then what's the use for the Fragment itself as a `LifecycleOwener`?

Comment: I'd argue that ViewModel did not help create more stable apps, because it has no direct `onSaveState/onRestoreState` support, and people are unaware of the viewmodel-savedstate module that provides the `SavedStateHandle`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are two different lifecycles because the Fragment itself lives longer than the Fragment's view.

There are a number of events that can cause the Fragment's view to be destroyed, but currently keep the Fragment itself alive:

1. Putting the Fragment on the back stack (i.e., when you `navigate()` to another Fragment)
2. Calling `detach()` on a Fragment
3. Calling `setMaxLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED)` on a Fragment

In these cases, the Fragment's view is destroyed, moving the Fragment view lifecycle to `DESTROYED`. However, the lifecycle of Fragment itself is **not** destroyed - it generally stays as `CREATED`. This means that the Fragment can go through multiple cycles of `onCreateView()` -> `onViewCreated()` -> `onDestroyView()` while only going through `onCreate()` once.

Where this becomes a problem is when it comes to how `LiveData` works. When you `observe` a `LiveData`, `LiveData` automatically unregisters the observer when the lifecycle reaches `DESTROYED`. But if you use the Fragment's lifecycle to `observe` in `onCreateView()`, etc., that registered observer will still exist after `onDestroyView()`, despite the view being destroyed. This means that the second time your Fragment goes through `onCreateView()`, you'll actually create a second active Observer, with both running simultaneously. Then three Observers the next time and on and on.

By using the view LifecycleOwner in `onCreateView()`/`onViewCreated()`, you ensure that you'll only have one active Observer running at a time and that Observers tied to previous view instances are correctly destroyed along with the view. Therefore, **yes, you should always use `getViewLifecycleOwner()` as the LifecycleOwner when in `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()`, including when using Data Binding.**

Of course, if you're registering an Observer in `onCreate()`, then the view LifecycleOwner does not exist yet (it is created right before `onCreateView()`) and you don't have the multiple registration problem, which is why the Lint check specifically does not apply to any registrations done at `onCreate()` time. In those cases, using the Fragment's lifecycle itself is absolutely correct.

As per the [Fragments: Past, Present, and Future talk](https://youtu.be/RS1IACnZLy4?t=956), one future improvements for Fragments is going to be combining the two lifecycles together, always destroying the Fragment whenever the Fragment's view is destroyed. This is not yet available in any shipped version of Fragments, alpha or otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. All in all, am I to believe there is almost no point in using the `Fragment` itself as a `LifecycleOwner` ?

Comment: @Mackovich - like I said, you can `observe` or add your own `LifecycleObserver` in `onCreate()`. Not everything lifecycle related is solely about filling your UI.

Comment: What about `DialogFragment`s? Is it always fine to not use the `viewLifecycleOwner` there?

Comment: @FredPorciúncula - DialogFragments don't go on the back stack, so their lifecycle ~always change  at the same time.

Comment: @ianhanniballake is there a way to handle the setmaxstate of the first fragments that are being loaded in the multiple back stack sample you preseted in Past/Present/future. I am asking because in that sample all fragments that are being added to a NavHost their state is set as setMaxLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.Resumed), this means that all the fragmets are going to run their viewmodel logic, calling rest services, etc, observe the changes, update the view, in all fragments that are setted as starting destination of the nav graphs, on the first load of the application. Any advice will be great

Comment: @Catluc - you can call `setMaxLifecycle()` in your copy of `NavigationExtensions`, sure.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thnks for the advice saddly its not working, because I belive it has something to do with this  NavHostFragment.create(navGraphId), under the hood is calling onCreate()/onAttach() and this methods sets up the state of the starting destination fragment of each graph.

Comment: @ianhanniballake In the end i found the solution, on setting navHost i had to set setMaxLifecycle to STARTED and when selecting the new navhost (on click on another button from bottomNavigationView) setMaxLifecycle to Resumed. "Its kind of ;)" hackish but it does the job, thank for ur time an advice, hope to see soon the new updates from navigation lib.